# Parsing radio button values from form to GA on button SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that I'm able to capture user selection from radio buttons that I have on the form as well as being able to capture what selected they make in a drop-down element. But the thing is I've only been able to capture these as events using .blur()

I need to be able to push this data to GA when the user clicks submit (which takes them to another step in the form).

I currently have this:

```
<script>
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(':input[name=HasPreviousHealthFund]').blur(function () {
        if($(this).val().length > 0) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Existing Health Insurance', 'completed', $(this).attr('value')]);
        } 
        else {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Existing Health Insurance', 'skipped', $(this).attr('value')]);
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This is showing events for each click on a radio button but I'm not sure how to trigger those events only on submission of the button.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It would help if you shared the html as well. However, I think using .blur() may not be the right approach here. You want to bind the `_gaq.push` event to when the submit button is clicked, not when the radio buttons lose focus (`.blur()`)

Answer (score 0):

Put your event handler on the `submit` event of the form, not on the buttons. It can then check which button is checked and perform the appropriate GA action.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var buttonValue = $(":input[name=HasPreviousHealthFund]:checked").val();
    var status = buttonValue.length > 0 ? 'completed' : 'skipped';
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Existing Health Insurance', status, buttonValue]);
});
```